# EF loading all children even with Where of FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have this code:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext(connectionString))
{
    context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
    context.Database.Log = logValue => File.AppendAllText(logFilePath, logValue);

    var testItem1 = context.ParentTable
                      .FirstOrDefault(parent => parent.Id == 1)
                      .ChildEntities
                      .FirstOrDefault(child => child.ChildId == 2000);
}
```

When executing this code and examining log file for EF 6 (logFilePath), I see that children entities are loaded for the entire ParentTable record with Id == 1, while LazyLoading is enabled and Where condition for child table is specified (child.ChildId == 2000).

Shouldn't EF load only relevant children or is reading Items executed first and then on in-memory data FirstOrDefault gets executed?

Because if some parent has many children entities, this way, it can significantly decrease performance when loading children with condition?

I guess the workaround would be to load children entities separately?

This is a complete log file for above code (some lines excluded for easier reading):

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
    ....
    FROM [dbo].[ParentTable] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[Id]

SELECT 
    ...
    FROM [dbo].[ChildTable] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ParentId] = @EntityKeyValue1
-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)
```

**NOTE: Added relevant classes:**

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ParentTable> ParentTable { get; set; }

    public DbSet<ChildTable> ChildTable { get; set; }

    static MyDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);
    }

    public MyDbContext(string connStr)
        : base(connStr)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ParentTable>()
            .HasMany(t => t.ChildEntities);
    }
}

[Table("ParentTable", Schema = "dbo")]
public class ParentTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ChildTable> ChildEntities { get; set; }
}

[Table("ChildTable", Schema = "dbo")]
public class ChildTable
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual ParentTable Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you show ParentTable  and ChildTable classes please?

Comment: Added at the end of the question

Answer (score 1):

use this query:

```
var testItem1 = context.ChildTables
                      .Include(p=>p.ParentTable)
                      .Where(ch => ch.ChildId == 2000)
                      .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks! Not quite exactly what I was looking for, but it will do. Still don't know why EF does not recognize this and make appropriate query :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with lazy loading. It is because you use `FirstOrDefault` too early in your sequence of LINQ methods.

I'll first write the proper query, then I'll explain why that one is better.

```
var result = dbContext.ParentTable
    .Where(parent => parent.Id == 1)
    .SelectMany(parent => parent.ChildEntities.Where(child => child.ChildId == 2000))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you look closely to the LINQ methods, you'll see there are two types: those that return `IQueryable<...>`, and the others. LINQ methods of the first group are use lazy execution, also called deferred execution. This means that these statements won't execute the query. They will only change the `Expression` in the IQueryable. The database is not queried yet.

LINQ statements from the latter group will deep inside call `GetEnumerator()` and most of the times repeatedly call `MoveNext() / Current`. This will send the `IQueryable.Expression` to the `IQueryable.Provider`, who will try to translate the Expression into SQL and execute the query to fetch data from the database (to be precise: the translation doesn't always have to be SQL, that depends on the Provider). The fetched data is presented as an `IEnumerator<...>`, of which you can call `MoveNext() / Current`.

Your first `FirstOrDefault` will already execute the query. Apart from that it is executed too early, and might fetch more data than you want, you can also have the problem that it returns `null`.

The proper method would be to use `Select`. Only the last statement should contain a non_IQueryable method like `FirstOrDefault`.

I used SelectMany instead of Select, because you are only interested in the ChildEntities of the Parent, not in any of the Parent properties.

```
var result = dbContext.ParentTable
    .Where(parent => parent.Id == 1)
    .SelectMany(parent => parent.ChildEntities.Where(child => child.ChildId == 2000))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Although this solves your problem, this will fetch more data than you actually plan to use. For instance, every Child will have a foreign key to the Parent. You know the Parent has a primary key value equal to 1, so the foreign key of the Child will also have a value of 1. Why transfer it?

In this case, I expect only one Child, so the problem is not too big. But in other cases you might be sending the same value often.

> When using entity framework, always use Select and select only the properties that you plan to use. Only fetch the complete row or use Include if you plan to update the fetched item.

Another thing that will slow down your process if you don't use Select, is that when you fetch complete rows, the original fetched data and a copy of it are put in the `DbContext.ChangeTracker`. This is done to make it possible to detect what values must be save when you call `SaveChanges`. If you don't plan to update the fetched data, don't waste processing power to put the fetched data in the change tracker.